# how to compare an string array?

Tags: java, arrays

i have this code example. I want to compare to strings that contains paths. The problem is at the else part...in this example they have / and usr together..and i want to compare the length after that point where they are different..thank you for your help

```
String path1 = "/usr/libexec/warmd";
String path2 = "/usr/lib/libOpen/xy";

String[] test1 = path1.split("/");
String[] test2 = path2.split("/");

ArrayList<String[]> path1array = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String[]> path2array = new ArrayList<String[]>();
path1array.add(test1);
path2array.add(test2);

int len1 = test1.length;
int len2 = test2.length;
int len;
if (len1 <= len2) {
    len = len1;
} else
    len = len2;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    if ((test1[i]).equals(test2[i])) {
        continue;
    } else
        break;
}
```

Comment: If these are just paths, you might want to look at the `Path` api.

Comment: This question sounds familiar somehow...

Comment: yes because someone delete it :( because i wrote its URGENT..i only want an idea, how can i solve it..

Comment: You really should tell what is your desired outcome, what you want to achieve, instead of debating a possible solution which very likely can be done better...

Comment: Your for loop is currently pointless... It either breaks or continues till it the condition fails (in which it "breaks"). Without clearly stating what you want it to do, we cannot help you with your question.

Comment: the desire is to find out how different the paths are..that is my solution that i tried..

Comment: Can you define what you mean by how "different" they are?

Comment: why its pointless? it continues till they have an different element, i know that the break is wrong..

Comment: Yes, that is correct... it will branch at the if statement when it reaches the point where the paths differ. The problem is your current code isn't doing anything when this happens. Look at the following two scenarios: If the two paths differ, it will get to the if statement and break. Now if the two paths are equal, it will continue to loop through the for loop until all the path elements are exhausted and the for loop will exit, producing identical output as simply breaking. If you already know the break statement is incorrect care to tell us what you want it to do instead?

Comment: ok i understand :) it should only give the length of the rest of the array and i want to compare the length of both rest arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the common prefix substring as follows :

```
int minLen = Math.min(test1.length, test2.length);
String commonPrefix = "";

for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
    if (test1[i].compareTo(test2[i]) == 0) {
        commonPrefix += test1[i]+"/";
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you don't like the String assignments, use a StringBuffer instaed. Now get the paths as :

```
String path1unique = path1.replaceFirst(commonPrefix, "");
String path2unique = path2.replaceFirst(commonPrefix, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure `String` manipulation, and forgetting about `File` objects, you can use `replaceFirst` or a combination of `substring` and `indexOf` to get rid of "/usr/" in your path `Strings`.

Here's an example:

```
// the input paths
String path1 = "/usr/libexec/warmd";
String path2 = "/usr/lib/libOpen/xy";
// gets "/usr/" in path1 and initializes a portion of path1 starting after 
// the length of "/usr/"
String comparablePath1 = path1.substring(path1.indexOf("/usr/") + "/usr/".length());
// replaces the first instance of literal (in this case) pattern "/usr/" in path1
String trimmedPath1 = path1.replaceFirst("/usr/", "");
System.out.println(comparablePath1);
System.out.println(trimmedPath1);
String comparablePath2 = path2.substring(path1.indexOf("/usr/") + "/usr/".length());
String trimmedPath2 = path2.replaceFirst("/usr/", "");
System.out.println(comparablePath2);
System.out.println(trimmedPath2);
// compares "comparable" paths
if (comparablePath1.length() > comparablePath2.length()) {
    System.out.println("1st path is longer");
}
else if (comparablePath2.length() > comparablePath1.length()) {
    System.out.println("2nd path is longer");
}
else {
    System.out.println("1st and 2nd paths are equal in length");
}
```

Output:

```
libexec/warmd
libexec/warmd
lib/libOpen/xy
lib/libOpen/xy
2nd path is longer
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :) but what will happen if it doesnt start with usr?

Comment: @Zeynep you're welcome. If it doesn't start with "/usr/", you'd need to change the "/usr/" literal in my example. Of course, I think you mean: "what happens if I don't know how it starts in advance?". In that case I suggest you loop through each character of the `String`s from start until you find a difference. Then you remove the equal part, and compare the different part. But that's for another SO question, now that you have the hang of it.

Comment: yes that is the problem.. i dont know it in advance :) yes thanks that will help..for sure :)